# Interpreting ARMA models?

Tags: arima

After much searching I was able to picture in my mind an ARMA model with this analogy:

- AR representing the sales of a given item.
- MA representing a coupon given for the item.

This analogy is given in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pg0RnP1uLVc)

Whenever I search for examples of ARMA I get examples of the math solving part. I also searched for 'analogies' with no luck.

My question is: is it ok to picture an ARMA model as sales(AR), and coupons(MA)? I would also like another analogy/example but I cannot come up with one. Any suggestions?

Comment: What area are you in? ARMA per se have no subject-matter interpretation, only a mathematical one. Hence, ARMA per se is not related to sales and coupons. One needs some subject-matter context to be able to interpret ARMA in subject-matter terms.

Comment: I am doing 'machine learning' online courses, and one touched briefly on 'time series'. I wanted to expand my knowledge, and I have little background in math, that is why 'analogies' help me to a great extent.

Comment: Sure. This is why I am asking what subject-matter area you have in mind. "Sales" and "coupon" give some hints, but could you just spell it out explicitly?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wrongly thought this mainly applied to 'Marketing'. I couldn't be more wrong. So 'Marketing' or an area closely related.